# Codeigniter Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying a simple code igniter hello world tutorial but keep getting this error and don't know why.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\loxxbylisa\application\controllers\helloworld.php on
>   line 3

```
<? php

    class HelloWorld extend CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
            $this->load->view('helloworld');
        }

    }

?>
```

I am running it in XAMPP and my helloworld.php in views folder is just the text "hello world". 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that jumps out at me right now is you have a space between your opening

```
class HelloWorld extends CI_Controller
```

Notice the "s" at the end of extend.  Should be extends. http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code it will work for you.. In controller ...you have use wrong spelling of extend...it should be extends

```
<?php

    class HelloWorld extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('helloworld');
        }

    }

?>
```

Create a view in the views with the name helloworld.php

Comment: Yes I have fixed that but the problem still remains.

Comment: the problem was the space after php.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while working with Codeignitor:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: ParseError
> Message: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)

My code was as follows:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed')

class Migrate extends CI_Controller
```

The problem here is that I should have ended the first line with a ;

Unexpected T_CLASS can therefore be the result of several typos. Always check your code!